# Packaging electron app for windows with jenkins and electron-packager in Linux

Tags: windows, ubuntu, jenkins, electron, wine

I'm trying to automate the build of an electron app using Jenkins. Before I did it using electron-packager directly on a windows PC (because the app is intended to be used in windows) but now that I want to use a Linux environment for the build process (ex. Ubuntu) I get the following error :

```
15:55:32 Packaging app for platform win32 ia32 using electron v1.8.7
15:55:36 WARNING: Found 'electron' but not as a devDependency, pruning anyway
15:56:21 Could not find "wine" on your system.
15:56:21 
15:56:21 Wine is required to use the appCopyright, appVersion, buildVersion, icon, and 
15:56:21 win32metadata parameters for Windows targets.
15:56:21 
15:56:21 Make sure that the "wine" executable is in your PATH.
15:56:21 
15:56:21 See https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager#building-windows-apps-from-non-windows-platforms for details.
```

Old Packaging script (defined in package.json)

```
electron-packager . test-app --overwrite --asar --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --prune=true --out=release-builds
```

As suggested I created a gulp script for the packaging:

```
var opts = {
    name: pkg.name,
    platform: 'win32',
    arch: 'ia32',                           // ia32, x64 or all
    dir: './',                       // source location of app
    out: './edist/',              // destination location for app os/native binaries
    asar: true, // compress project/modules into an asar blob but don't use asar to pack the native compiled modules
    overwrite: true,
    prune: true,
    electronVersion: electronVersion ,       // Tell the packager what version of electron to build with
    appCopyright: pkg.copyright,            // copyright info
    appVersion: pkg.version,         // The version of the application we are building
    win32metadata: {                        // Windows Only config data
        CompanyName: pkg.authors,
        ProductName: pkg.name,
        FileDescription: pkg.description,
        OriginalFilename: pkg.name + '.exe'
    }
};

    gulp.task('build:electron', done =>  {

        console.log('Launching task to package binaries for ' + opts.name + ' v' + opts['appVersion']);

    packager(opts).then(appPaths => {
            console.log(' PackagerDone(). appPaths :  ', appPaths);

        var zippedPromises = appPaths.map(function (appPath) {
            console.log('Preparing pipe for zip ', appPath + ".zip");
            return zipFolder(appPath, appPath + ".zip");
        });

        Promise.all(zippedPromises).then(function () {
            console.log(' Zip file created.');        
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error, error.stack);
        });    

        done();
    });

    });
```

which again, works in Windows, but returns the same Error on Ubuntu. 
(zipFolder converts the release folder in a zip file, it is just an extra function I wrote)

My question is, is it possible to just not install wine at all and make it work ?

Comment: Can you show your code for packaging?

Comment: Do you mean the one I have to define in package.json for electron-packager? I added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, the solutions could be, either run the build script directly in a Windows environment, or install Wine under Linux (where Jenkins was 'living'). The idea from @Kim Gentes helped me thought, specially to organized the build script in a better and more readable way.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can use the `electron-packager` API more effectively when trying to run in a build script/Jenkins environment. At least, that is what I found. This allows you to configure and parameterize your building much more succinctly.

In our case, we wrapped the `electron-packager` in a nice `gulp` script to make it build nicely and to be nicely callable from Jenkins.

This link might give you a sense of how to go about it and the standard components that would be good to use:

[Example of Building an Electron app with `electron-packager`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46693219/3946706)

Comment: I installed gulp and created a script, which is called from command promp line in a linux env (Ubuntu), and I still have a problem because 'wine' is not installed.